# How to change a property retrieved by Get-PnPField if there's no Set-PnPField?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp, pnp-powershell

I all,

I really appreaciate what PnP for O365 has enabled us to do so far.
I was wondering how I can change the setting on a list column to require or not require a value. In the GUI this option is named "Require that this column contains information".

I was able to retrieve this setting with `Get-PnPField -List 'LibraryTitle' | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "ColumnName"} | Select Required`

This evaluates to either true or false. However, I have no idea how to change this value as Set-PnPField does not exist.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure when it was added, but PnP powershell does have the `Set-PnPField` command available.

I would suggest that you update to the latest PnP powershell.

You can run the below command to update it to the latest version:

```
Update-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell*
```

Or you, can download it from the below link, it will overwrite the current installation.

Download link - [PnP PowerShell releases](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Once this is done, you can set the value of a field to required as below:

```
Set-PnPField -List 'LibraryTitle' -Identity 'ColumnName' -Values @{Required=$true}
```

Reference - [Set-PnPField](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/SetPnPField.md)

Comment: hey @colonel_claypoo, did you try the above approach ? did it work for you ?

Comment: your code worked for me. PNP commands are updated often, so +1 to check often. I see updates as recent as 10 days from me posting this. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

If it is first time creation of field, remove the field using remove-PnPField -List "listname" -identity "guid of field" and add-pnpfield with -required parameter.

```
Add-PnPField [-AddToDefaultView [<SwitchParameter>]]
             [-Required [<SwitchParameter>]] // true
             [-Group <String>]
             [-Web <WebPipeBind>]
```